# How to define CallBack and Raises methods for the same Moq class SetUp method definition?

Tags: c#, methods, installation, moq

I would like to define CallBack and Raises functions for the same MoqClass.Method. I assume, the CalllBack in the example below does not  work because,  the second Setup definition overrides the first one.

```
 MoqClass.Setup(x => x.Method()).Callback(bla,bla,bla);
 MoqClass.Setup(x => x.Method()).Raises(bla,bla,bla)
```

Is my assumption correct? If yes, how can I set up both CallBack and Raises for the same Moq method?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you combine the callback and the event together as a single action?: () = > {execute the event; execute the callback;}

Comment: why do you need to setup both a Callback _and_ a Raises in the first place? could you be more explicit about the final goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If anything, .Callback and .Raises in sequence or .Setup(bla,bla,bla).Callback(bla,bla,bla).Raises(bla,bla,bla) would look a lot cleaner...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have to do something like this:

```
MoqClass.Setup(x => x.Method()).Callback(() =>
    {
        //Your Callback logic
        var x = "foo":

        //Your Raises logic
        MoqClass.Raise(x => x.Foo += null, new FooEventArgs
        {
            Bar = true
        });
    });
```